# Permission Error: Permission denied: 'analyticsreporting.dat'

Tags: google-analytics-api

I've been trying to use the core reporting API v4 to access google analytics data, using the python sample code provided: 
*https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py*

After passing the stage where I am prompted to give permission,

[image]

I got the following error message:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Z:\PythonDocs\HelloAnalytics.py", line 85, in <module> main()
File "Z:\PythonDocs\HelloAnalytics.py", line 80, in main 
analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
File "Z:\PythonDocs\HelloAnalytics.py", line 41, in 
initialize_analyticsreporting
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
File "Z:\PythonDocs\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in 
positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "Z:\PythonDocs\oauth2client\tools.py", line 247, in run_flow
storage.put(credential)
File "Z:\PythonDocs\oauth2client\client.py", line 421, in put
self.locked_put(credentials)
File "Z:\PythonDocs\oauth2client\file.py", line 83, in locked_put
self._create_file_if_needed()
File "Z:\PythonDocs\oauth2client\file.py", line 70, in _create_file_if_needed
open(self._filename, 'a+b').close()
**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'analyticsreporting.dat'****
```

---

I checked my directory and the file 'analyticsreporting.dat' is there.
Anyone had the same issue?  I appreciate any input!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the dat file and running the code again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, still get the same error, "Permission denied".

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like the python process doesn't have permissions. Can you modify the permission of the file so that all users can read & write to it?

Answer (score 0):

The python script doent have permissions over the .dat file you may need to use [chmod](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) over it or run the script with [sudo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

Other solution may be changing where you are executing your script to a path where the system user has access (try the desktop).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends from how exactly you are executing you Python script.

In case you are not executing it directly from the same folder where your python script and `analyticsreporting.dat` files located - you need to specify also working directory.

See related topics:

[SSIS Execute Process Task for Python script to API with OAuth2 - Access denied to the file with saved token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008354/ssis-execute-process-task-for-python-script-to-api-with-oauth2-access-denied-t/55022134#55022134)

[SSIS Execute Process Task Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873544/ssis-execute-process-task-python-script/55022263#55022263)