# How can I run .py script in SSIS without converting to either .bat or .exe

Tags: python, ssis

I need to run a .py python script from within SSIS.. However I don't want to convert my .py file to either .bat or .exe since my script has used multiprocess module and when I convert it to either .bat or .exe and run it through SSIS package, it generate dozens of processes which as I searched through the net, its probably because of multiprocessing.... therefore I don't want to convert my file to these executables and want to directly run my .py file from within SSIS.

The SSIS execute task is configured as bellow:

[image]

But I get this error:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
>   ""D:\SLA\SLA_Report\temp.py"" at "D:\SLA\SLA_Report", The process exit
>   code was "1" while the expected was "0".

The code has  successfully executed from within Spyder and therefore there is no error in code.

Moreover as I searched the stack overflow and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873544/ssis-execute-process-task-python-script), I have specified the "working folder property" of Execute Process Task and there is no space in my directory.

So any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT:***

The actual output of the package is as below:
[image]

The account name of SSIS is as below:

[image]

Comment: Is D an actual drive, a mapped network drive, a substituted drive? When the SSIS package runs, what account is running the SSIS package?

Comment: Also, capture the standard out/error to variables and then you can see what is being emitted by the task (if it's not already available in the output window)

Comment: @billinkc Drive D is an actual drive and I guess "NT Service\MsDtsServer140" is the account of SSIS.

Comment: @billinkc I have also edited my question and added the actual output message of the package. Thanks for your help

Comment: The MsDtsServer140 virtual user is used for licensing stuff. When you run the package - how do you do so? Double click? Create an SQL Agent job? Just command line `dtexec Package5.dtsx`?

Comment: @billinkc I simply click on the “Start” button, the green play icon...

Comment: When you click the play icon, you are running the package within Visual Studio Data Tools, which means you are logged in as you. Which means there should not be a permissions issue of you accessing `C:\Users\mpy\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe` which if this were on a server, could present challenges

Comment: Change from pythonw to python. Any chance things are radically different?

Comment: Was there a difference in behaviour between using python vs pythonw?

Comment: @billinkc Sorry for delay in answering. Unfortunately no... I still got the issue and I eventually had to convert my .py file into exe. Thanks for your follow up

Answer (score 0):

In the Arguments section just mention "temp.py" the python script file name instead of whole path again